# Why is a question like this protected?

Tags: discussion

I'm not asking specifically about this question:
[How do they film “flying human” scenes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2153/how-do-they-film-flying-human-scenes)

but just generally... (especially since I don't have a better answer than the one posted).

This question only has one answer, which has been accepted, and has very few comments.

But, it has been protected:

> Thank you for your interest in this question. Because ***it has attracted low-quality answers***, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site.

So, "protection" doesn't seem to fit well with this question.

Answer (score 2):

On the specific question, no I don't know why.  As you can see in @AnkitSharma's answer, one answer was converted to a comment by me, but it was not protected at that time.  2 days later the comment was deleted and the question protected.

On the general point. IMHO there is probably no good reason to protect a question like this.  Its more typical to react to a question that has attracted 2-3 poor answers from low rep (usually unregistered) users.

However being proactive can sometimes be helpful.  Sometimes you can 'just tell' when a question is likely to attract multiple poor answers - for example its a very hot topic, the question is getting a lot of views quickly, its a question that might be somewhat controversial and/or has already got one poor answer.  For example TylerShads protected a [Game of Thrones Question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19880/what-is-the-perception-of-tyrions-story-about-his-cousin-orson-and-the-beetles) about this Sunday's episode, that already has 13k views and one poor answer.

An example of a more reactive stance is [this question about Top Gear](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11516/did-james-may-richard-hammond-and-jeremy-clarkson-really-find-out-the-source-of) which is a year old but has 10k views and has a result has attracted 3 very poor (now deleted) answers - that are basically 'forum-like' comments.  I protected this yesterday, as its clearly got a history and with the general popularity of Top Gear is likely to continue to attract answers like this, and eventually be protected by Community anyway.

I would stress however that moderation is a judgement call - mistakes are made.  High rep users here can unprotect if they think its unnecessary, or if the time in which it might have been necessary has passed.  Ping a mod in chat if you are unsure, or don't have the unprotect powers yourself.  I personally have a 'lighter touch' than TylerShads - but put another way that means I'm being less proactive about protection.

Answer (score 1):

The same question have one deleted answer, i think your reputation is low so you can't see it.  Refer screen-shot below.

[image]

That might be the reason for being it protected. I have unprotected it for now.

Comment: Well, 1 comment-non-answer alone still seems not enough to warrant a protection of the question. Usually it takes like 3 or so non-answers from 1-rep users on a question with already many answers (and the possibility to generate further non-answers) to take someone to protecting it. So I can't help but agree with *Kevin* that protection doesn't seem like a good fit for this question. Otherwise we could just protect anything where a non-answer ever appears, but this would close out new users from answering like half of the questions around here.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson i am agree with you but as kevin said, he can only see one accepted answer, so just shared deleted answer with him. Anyways i have just unprotected it because i think there could be more good answer to it.

Comment: I didn't know one can that easily unprotect questions.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson i though i can't over-right Mod's protect power but it got worked.